# PyQt application crashes the second time it calls error message

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

**Context:**
I'm creating a GUI using QtDesigner and PyCharm. The issue I am having occurs when the main window (win1) calls a second windows (win2) through a QPushButton, and then opens an error message due to lack of user input. I am using an external file (main.py) to handle the logic and events of all the windows, rather than editing code generated by QtDesigner.

**Issue:**
The way I have things set up, the user needs to pick an option from a comboBox, based on the user's selection, the application launches either win2 or win3

> User picks no option from comboBox --> Error message
>   User picks option 1 --> win2 opens, win1 closes
>   User picks option 2 --> win3 opens, win1 closes
>   The problem occurs after user exits win 2/3 and goes back to win1
>   User picks option 1/2 --> correct window opens, no issues
>   User picks no option --> error message --> user closes error
>   message --> crash (or sudden application exit)
>   **Note:** The crash produces no errors/warnings

Here's the code I'm using to handle the opening/closing:

```
class win1(QtGui.QMainWindow, pg1.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(win1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.checkuserselection)
        self.addnew = win2(self)

    def checkuserselection(self):
        user_str = str(self.comboBox.currentText())
        if user_str == "Select Option":
            self.errMsg()
        elif user_str == "Option 1":
            self.runaddnew("Window title for option 1")
        else:
            self.runaddnew("window title for option 2")

    def runaddnew(self, title):
        self.addnew.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.addnew.show()
        self.hide()

    @staticmethod
    def errMsg():
        w = QtGui.QMessageBox()
        QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(w, "No Option Selected!")
```

The code for win2:

```
class win2(QtGui.QMainWindow, pg2.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(win2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.closeWindow)

    def closeWindow(self):
        self.close()
        w = win1(self)
        w.show()
```

The user can get the error message many times without the application suddenly quitting, as long as they haven't opened one of the other windows. This leads me to think that the issue is with the closeWindow method in win2. My knowledge in python/pyQt is limited, so I don't know if that's indeed where the issue is.

Comment: You are passing 'self' to win1, which refers to a closed window. Qt is probably just not showing windows that are descendants of closed windows. Try starting it without a parent instead

Comment: I just did that, the application now exits as soon as actionExit on win2 is triggered, win1 is not showing up at all. I also tried reversing the order: w = win1(), w.show(), self.close(). That didn't work either. I also just tried w=win1 (no parenthesis) and it returns an error since win1 is no longer identified as a QWidget, and so doesn't have a .show() method

Comment: If `w` has no parent, you need to keep an explicit reference to it, otherwise it will be garbage-collected as soon as `closeWindow` returns.

Comment: @ekhumoro, can you please elaborate? What does it mean to keep an explicit reference? where does such a reference go in the code?

Comment: @YazMajeed. Actually, it looks like you don't need to create another `win1` at all. Just do `self.parent().show(); self.close()` and get rid of the other two lines.

Comment: Thank you @ekhumoro, that resolved the issue. Can you please clarify why it works though? My init method for win2 defines parent=None, but parent.show works, how?

Comment: @YazMajeed. Because you passed `self` to `win2` when you created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ekhumoro, I'm posting the response that worked here in case anyone else has this issue.
In the code for win2:

```
def closeWindow(self):
    self.parent().show()
    self.close()
```

This works because win1 passed self to win2 when win2 was created

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about this, looks like I can only do that in 5 hours for some reason, I'll make a note to come back here and do that